# Chat option in not Available

Tags: chatter

I am surprised as this issue happened to me.

**The chat option in the right bottom side of the screen is not available to many of the users of my org.**

The option is available to me when i logged in as admin but the option is not available when i logged in as one of the user of my org.

I also checked the chatter settings of my org that are already enabled.

I also checked the compatibility view turned off of the internet explorer. But still the chat option is not available.

Can anyone help me on this ? Is there any need to log a case on Salesforce Support ?

I will really appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this when viewing a VF page or always (when viewing standard layouts/tabs) as well

Comment: It is always. Chat is not available anywhere.

Comment: check:  It is available for internal users only when the organization-wide default for the user object is set to Public Read Only.

Comment: checked : OWD default internal access for User object is public Read Only.

Comment: Is there anything else to check ?

Comment: Can anyone help me on this? Thanks in advance.